# CSS: how can I do this page responsive?

Tags: css

I have this map with animals on it, but it doesn't look good on mobile/tablet and higher desktop resolutions.
The page is here: https://rianco.ro/map/

Thank you in advance,
A

[the screenshot is made with iphone6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHMhD.jpg)

[image]
    The code for the map is:

```
.harta-links {width:60px;height:60px;position:absolute;background-color:#f00;background:url(https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/pin.png) center center no-repeat;background-size: contain;}
.harta-links:hover {margin-top:-4px;}
.harta-links img {width: 39px;margin: 2px 0px 0px 11px;}
 #zoom {width:20px; height:20px;border:1px solid #000;}
```

The code to add an animal on the map is:

```
<img class="aligncenter" src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/harta_mare-1.jpg" alt="">
<div id="link-1" class="harta-links multilinks" style="top: 210px; left: 338px;"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_barza-alba.png"> <a class="harta-links suplimentar" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" href="/atlas/barza-alba">
<img src="upload/caroline.png"></a> <a class="harta-links suplimentar" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" href="/atlas/gasca-canadiana"><img src="upload/gasca-canadiana.png"></a></div>
<a id="link-2" class="harta-links" style="top: 262px; left: 154px;" href="/atlas/cangur-dama"><img src="upload/thumb/thumb_cangur-dama.png"></a>  <a id="link-31" class="harta-links" style="top: 332px; left: 958px;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_antilopa-eland.png"></a> <a id="link-32" class="harta-links" style="top: 312px; left: 916px;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_calul.png"></a> <a id="link-33" class="harta-links" style="top: 287px; left: 874px;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_cerb-lopatar.png"></a> <a id="link-34" class="harta-links" style="top: 268px; left: 831px;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_zebra.png"></a> <a id="link-35" class="harta-links" style="top: 243px; left: 777px;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_strut-emu.png"></a>
<a id="link-35" class="harta-links" style="top: 213px; left: 807px;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/"><img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_zebu.png"></a>
```

Comment: To make it responsive it's the easiest to either learn to work with Bootstrap or CSS grid

Comment: My issue is that I'm not that good in CSS or Javascript and need a real help here :) :) :)

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on YouTube to get you started with bootstrap. Once you get the idea it's not that hard to use. I'd really recommend looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {//Here set width on which you want to apply code bellow
   //Your css here for resolution under 600px
}
```

You can research a little bit css media query for responsive layout.

Here is some links for that.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know where the documentation is.
I need some help in using documentation, just an example how to put an animal on that map.

And to be responsive :)

Comment: Here si example of one animal, really I can't do it for all, but here on this example you can se how.
-Move inline CSS , and put them in class, than that class wrapp in media query from my post for mobile resolution, also class harta-links end everthng you need to look difirent on smaller resolution

<a id="link-2" class="harta-links" style="    top: 35%;
    left: 15%;" href="/atlas/cangur-dama"><img src="upload/thumb/thumb_cangur-dama.png" style=""></a>

Comment: Thank you Kadir, I saw a difference according to your advice but still yet to do. So I modified the code like this:
**.harta-links {width:6%;height:6%;position:absolute;background-color:#f00;background:url(https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/pin.png) center center no-repeat;background-size: contain;}
.harta-links:hover {margin-top:-4px;}
.harta-links img {width: 39px;margin: 2px 0px 0px 11px;}
 #zoom {width:20px; height:20px;border:1px solid #000;}**

Comment: and **@media (max-width:600px){
<img class="aligncenter" src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/harta_mare-1.jpg" alt="">
<div id="link-1" class="harta-links multilinks" style="top: 210px; left: 338px;">
<img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_barza-alba.png"> 
<a class="harta-links suplimentar" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" href="/atlas/barza-alba">
<img src="upload/caroline.png"></a>**

Comment: **<a class="harta-links suplimentar" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" href="/atlas/gasca-canadiana"><img src="upload/gasca-canadiana.png"></a></div>
<a id="link-2" class="harta-links" style="top: 35%; left: 15%;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/">
<img src="https://rianco.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumb_cangur-dama.png"></a> 
<a id="link-31" class="harta-links" style="top: 15%; left: 45%;" href="https://rianco.ro/python/">}**
but still need help, pleasseeee :)

Comment: You cannot put html in css media query,  in media wuery you only can put css code, move inline css from html to class, named it whatever you want, and then that class put in media query and in html where is need